# Right-align the prebreak symbol in a listings environment

Tags: listings, line-breaking, align

I’m using the `breaklines` and `prebreak` option with listings, but I find it visually not very pleasing that the prebreak-symbols are not vertically aligned. I’d prefer if they were all on the very right of the listing.

Here is example code.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines,breakatwhitespace,prebreak=!,basicstyle=\ttfamily]
This is a long line This is a long line This is a long line This is a long line This is a long line
This is another long line This is another long line This is another long line This is another long line
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Which yields:

[image]

while I want something like

[image]

Comment: The `listings` documentation warns against using spaces (other than `\space`) in the token list for `prebreak` and `postbreak`: "You must not use dynamic space (in particular spaces) since internally we use
`\discretionary`. However `\space` is redefined to be used inside tokens." The required alignment might be hard to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more or less ugly hack is the following. Instead of putting the prebreak symbol in the current line you can put the symbol inside the margin. The distance between the margin and the text body is given by `marginparsep`. So you can simple adjust it. The example needs two compilation steps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines,breakatwhitespace,prebreak={\def\marginnotevadjust{-\baselineskip}\marginnote{\llap{!\hspace*{\marginparsep}}}},basicstyle=\ttfamily]
This is a long line This is a long line This is a long line This is a long line This is a long line
This is another long line This is another long line This is another long line This is another long line
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Hmm, I don’t remember for what document I needed this, but I’ll keep it in mind for next time; it seems to be un-hacky enough :-)

Comment: Great, but apparently it does not work with e.g. `frame=single` though.

Answer (score 2):

Just stumbled upon this thread because I had the same question. Although, the thread is old, I thought about sharing this: By accident I found the following solution which works quite perfect for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  breaklines=true,
  prebreak={\mbox{\quad$\rhookswarrow$}},
  numbers=right,
  numberstyle={\ttfamily\scriptsize},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
RewriteRule ^/wms/(.+)$ /cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?map=/srv/www/assip/data/mapdb/$1.qgs [QSA,PT]
RewriteRule ^/maps/([^\.]+)$ /qgis-web-client/site/qgiswebclient.html [PT]
RewriteRule ^/maps/(.*) /qgis-web-client/site/$1 [PT]
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

This is an example I just took from a document I am working on:

[image: listing with break character being aligned right]

The symbol I used is from `\usepackage{MnSymbol}`. I am not sure why this works but I guess that `\quad` simultaneously forces the break earlier and 'pushes' the break character far right. At least it looks like it's right-aligned.

Comment: Unfortunately, I just found out that it's not working in every case.

Comment: Please post complete examples always

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry, I updated my answer. The above example is now "working" in a way that compiling it with `pdflatex` generates a valid PDF file but it is not a solution to the original answer as already stated in my previous comment.